# Sorting Model with Specific Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I would like to sort data of my model base on a specific order.

```
Model: Grade
Table Column: category, value
values of category: Prelim, Midterm, Semi-finals, Finals
```

How do I sort the table Grade base on it's category with value of "Prelim, Midterm, Semi-Finals, Finals"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you dont want to replace them by numbers in the table as suggested by @titibouboul . You can just do.

```
class Grade
   CATEGORY_IN_ORDER = ["Prelim", "Midterm", "Semi-Finals", "Finals"] 
   scope :ordered_by_category, lambda {"order(FIELD(category,#{CATEGORY_IN_ORDER.join(',')}))"}
end
```

then anywhere you can use this scope as:

```
 Grade.ordered_by_category.where(YOUR_CRITERIA)
```

if you dont want to define scopes:

```
Grade.where(YOUR_CRITERIA).order("FIELD(category,#{CATEGORY_IN_ORDER.join(',')})")
```

More about order by FIELD syntax here:
http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-order-specific-field-values/

Comment: @fujisan i dont think this is dependent of rails version. Just try `Grade.where("category is not null").order("FIELD(category,#{CATEGORY_IN_ORDER.join(',')})")` . Its pure mysql syntax.

Comment: I have already used it as my default scope. Thanks again for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace them by a number :

```
1 = Prelim 
2 = Midterm
3 = Semi-finals
4 = Finals
```

and then sort them in the model like this :

```
class Grade
...
default_scope -> { order('category ASC') }
...
end
```

Comment: Prelim, Midterm, Semi-finals and finals are values of category so I won't be able to change them right now.

Comment: I would not recommend using default_scope: http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/806-default_scope-is-evil

Comment: default_scope has gotten less crappy in Rails 4, for the record.